# Creating a button on leftswipe of a listview

Tags: android, listview, button, swipe

This is an extended question of  [Displaying a button when a Listview is Swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901125/displaying-a-button-when-a-listview-is-swipe)

I have found a Onswipetouchlistener from the internet and have added to the class now my question is when i swipe a button is created but my requirement is the button should be created for each row or to be more precise, The button should be created on the row which is swiped. Please help

I have attached the code below

My MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.listviewswipe;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;


import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.GestureDetector;// files for using Swipe functions
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.View;

public class Mainpage extends Activity  {

    String[] name;
    ListView listview;
    swipedetector swipe;
    Button btn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainpage);
        name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Mainpage.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name);
        listview.setAdapter(adp);
        listview.setOnTouchListener(swipe);

        listview.setOnTouchListener(new onswipelistener(){

            public void onSwipeRight(){
                btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        });






    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainpage, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

My OnSwipeTouchListener class

```
package com.example.listviewswipe;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

/**
 * Detects swipes on views. See {@link http
 * ://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288
 * /android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures}
 */
public class onswipelistener implements OnTouchListener {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "OnSwipeTouchListener";

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    /**
     * {@link SimpleOnGestureListener} implementation which detects left, right,
     * up and down swipes.
     */
    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            super.onLongPress(motionEvent);
            onLongPressDetected(motionEvent);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            // by default, don't consume the event
            boolean consumeEvent = false;
            try {
                if (e1 != null && e2 != null) {
                    float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                    float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY) && Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD
                            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                        consumeEvent = true;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onFling", exception);
            }
            return consumeEvent;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onLongPressDetected(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    }

    public void setIsLongpressEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        gestureDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(enabled);
    }
}
```

My XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Mainpage" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp" >
    </ListView>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1:**
You need to create a custom adapter with custom view (eg custom base adapter)

**Step-2:**
Place the button in the view which will be inflated in that adapter

**Step-3:**
add your onSwipeliostener to the view of the adapter and perform the activity to show or hide button there

[example of list view with custom adapter](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/android-listview-example-with-custom-adapter/)

Answer (score 0):

These link will be helpful for implementing swipe listener with listview in android.

https://coderwall.com/p/dpfrcw

Library.
https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview