# Setting ItemTouchHelper swipe final distance

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[Swipe ListView item From right to left show delete button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797099/swipe-listview-item-from-right-to-left-show-delete-button)

Is there a way to get this behavior with `ItemTouchHelper`?

I know how to show the image underneath but I'm not sure how to get it to stop at a specific distance.

Comment: I would recommend using a third party library. Itemtouchhelper supports only basic functions. --> Advanced RecyclerView

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: No.  I ended up using this library instead.
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout