# android swipe listview similar to screenshot

Tags: android, listview, swipe-gesture

I made an app. It has a listView and want to implement in it a right swipe action. Exactly like in [this example](http://postimg.org/image/nc6ijzeep/). Is there anything similar defined in android or library that does exactly the same as in the screenshot ?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797099/swipe-listview-item-from-right-to-left-show-delete-button

Comment: i think this links can help you https://github.com/hudomju/android-swipe-to-dismiss-undo , https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/swipe-listview/

Here is an example, easy to implement and don't have to use third party library.

Good luck!